# Can anyone tell me what a white space appear between the footer and the social links stripe?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am wondering if this question is adequate here at all....but I have faced this problem that I cant solve.

Everything works find on my website...but for some reason I cant get rid of this white stripe between the footer and the social buttons stripe. Any ideas why that is?

Here is the website: http://gaberivers.com/prueba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CSS  for #socialfooter and reduce its height to be 30px;

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the problem. Can you tell me why it has to be 30px while the actual height of the png image is 40px? I thought in the css file I need to specify the dimension of the png image (900px*40px) to make it appear fully.

Comment: @Elysium This due to margin values of the next element.

Comment: I thought the height and width refer to the size of the actual <div>. I honestly dont understand how the footer div messed up the socialfooter due to margin values. In fact...I dont even know what my margin values are in the index.html. I am newbie to all these things, and still learning. Thanks a lot for the help.